# Spring Web Flux, best way to combine Flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

Little bit of context :
I have 2 spring data (mongodb)

- stockRepository
- reservationRepository

A stock have (among others, irrelevant for the question, properties) a sublist of "reserved stocks" which just having a quantity and an id
A reservation is a object with a status and in addition of its id some other properties like commandIdentifier and lineIdentifier

My goal is to create a method which can call for a stock a new object with

- the reference of the product
- some properties link to the product
- the list of the concerned reservations with command and line identifiers

I'm new to Webflux and I'm struggling with the following code

```
return stockRepository.findById(id) //id of the stock is passed to the method
          .map(stock -> {
                List<String> reservationIds = getReservationIds(stock)
                Flux<Reservation> reservationFlux = reservationRepository.findAllById(reservationIds)
                return new StockResponse(
                             stock.getId(),
                             // other properties from stock object,
                             reservationFlux.collectList().block()
                                
            });
```

I'm feeling that it is not the best approach for this, but I can't see how to to this properly.

nb : This method will be called from a RestController to display the StockResponse within a web ui.

Comment: `.block()` -- wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `block`, make it in a reactive way:

```
    stockRepository.findById(id) //id of the stock is passed to the method
            .flatMap(stock -> {
                List<String> reservationIds = getReservationIds(stock);
                Flux<Reservation> reservationFlux = reservationRepository.findAllById(reservationIds);
                Mono<List<Reservation>> allReservationsMono = reservationFlux.collectList();
                return allReservationsMono.map(reservationsList -> new StockResponse(
                        stock.getId(),
                        // other properties from stock object,
                        reservationsList
                );
            });
```

Also make sure `getReservationIds` is nonblocking. Otherwise, look if it's possible to make reactive and return `Flux`/`Mono`.

Comment: I agree with you on the block, but reservationsList will be a Mono and not a List, so how the UI will parse this ?

Comment: I've just tried your solution and I'm getting :
    "reservations": {
        "scanAvailable": true
    }

Comment: `allReservationsMono` is a `Mono`, `reservationsList` is a `List<Reservation>` . And whole solution should return `Flux<StockResponse>` just as your original one. Doesn't it? I couldn't check without all auxiliary classes used there.

Comment: Why do you get "reservations": { "scanAvailable": true } depends on a multiple factors: What do you return from RestController, what repository returns, how does StockResponse serialize. Check with debugger/logging what is teh values of reservationsList, StockResponse, etc

Comment: I didn't realised you had changed the collectList(), with your code, everything is good, thank you